# officials worry he and the GOP could starve it

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Trump can't postpone the election, but officials worry he and the GOP could starve it*

Source: https://www.yahoo.com/news/trump-cant-postpone-election-officials-150757454.html

I am not able to understand the reason why the officials should worry. What substantive does "it" replace? Is it an election?

PS: I have not read the full article below this title.

Comment: **It** refers to the election. Officials worry that Trump and the Republicans could drain the election of its validity. They could cause people to doubt the process or result.

Comment: Headlines are not designed to inform, but to attract interest in an article—the non-electronic version of clickbait. Because [tag:headlinese] is extremely elliptical and has other peculiar conventions, sometimes it's necessary even for native speakers to read the article in order to figure out what a headline means, as in [crash blossoms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/crash-blossom-words-were-watching).